# LitElement: Calling requestUpdate() from attributeChangedCallback() doesn't update (render)

Tags: polymer, web-component, lit-element

When I call `this.requestUpdate()` from within `attributeChangedCallback(...)` after I changed a classMap the render function is not called.

When I call it with a timeout it does seem to work. Is this the way to do it or is this a bug?

```
attributeChangedCallback(name: string, oldVal: AttributeType, newVal: AttributeType) {
    super.attributeChangedCallback(name, oldVal, newVal);

  ...
  
  this.myClassMap = {
    ...this.myClassMap,
    foo: newValueBasedOnChangedProperty,
  }

  // this doesn't seem to do anything
  this.requestUpdate(); 
  
  // this does trigger a re-render
  setTimeout(() => this.requestUpdate(), 0); 
}
```

What also seems to work is waiting for the updateComplete promise using this:

```
this.updateComplete.then(
  () => this.requestUpdate()
);
```

But it still feels like I'm putting the cart before the horse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour I described above seems to be related to property changing in combination with reflection. See this [issue](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/1167) on the LitElement GitHub repo for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `await element.updateComplete.then(() => this.requestUpdate());`